# How to generate 32-bit .exe file in NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm, 16-bit

I am using NASM to learn Assembly language but the NASM is generating 16-Bit .exe
which is not running on 32-Bit as well as 64-Bit OS I tried using NTVDM(on 32-Bit)
But the result is same. when I am trying to run my .exe file it is saying.
"This file cannot run on your PC find the right version for your PC".

I used this: command to generate 32 bit .exe but it is not working.

```
 nasm -f win32 test.asm -o test.o
```

AND

Please suggest any NASM(Assembly) tutorial for windows.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to link test.o to an executable.You don't show how you do that. One popular linker if you don't have a GNU tool chain installed is [ALINK](https://sourceforge.net/projects/alink/)

Comment: You need to have [BITS 32] in your source code.

Comment: I know your question is assuming win32; but on Linux OS I do "nasm -f elf32 -g -F dwarf test.s -o test.o && gcc test.o -o test -m32".  What are you using to handle linking?